# How to extract bike listings using information from 3taps API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

Developing a Ruby on Rails app using information from the 3 taps API. The information I want is from Craigslist. Want to extract information on bikes for sale in the UK.

the following gives me the category information for bikes for sale

```
{
            "code": "SBIK",
            "group_code": "SSSS",
            "group_name": "For Sale",
            "name": "Bicycles"
        },
```

so in my browser i add the following

http://polling.3taps.com/poll?auth_token=fxxxxxxxxx4a23a1cc86e0d&anchor=2109915749&source=CRAIG&category_group=SSSS&category=SBIK

```
{
"success": true,
"anchor": 2110058535,
"postings": [
{
"id": 2109916051,
"source": "CRAIG",
"category": "SBIK",
"external_id": "5010763041",
"external_url": "http://wilmington.craigslist.org/bik/5010763041.html",
"heading": "WTB:  Tri-bike...56-58cm",
"timestamp": 1430838700,
"annotations": {
"source_map_yahoo": "http://maps.yahoo.com/#mvt=m&amp;lat=34.157200&amp;lon=-77.914100&amp;zoom=16",
"source_continent": "USA",
"latlong_source": "In Posting",
"source_heading": "WTB:  Tri-bike...56-58cm",
"source_cat": "sss",
"proxy_ip": "104.236.116.193:22225",
"source_state": "North Carolina",
"phone": "5010763041",
"source_account": "5hz2n-5010763041@sale.craigslist.org",
"gzip_data_size": "4170",
"source_loc": "wilmington",
"source_subcat": "bia|bik",
"html_data_size": "12631",
"source_map_google": "https://maps.google.com/maps/preview/@34.157200,-77.914100,16z"
},
```

but when i add the country code -which is GBR i get nothing i have added
http://polling.3taps.com/poll?auth_token=fa95xxxxxxxx3a1cc86e0d&anchor=2109915749&source=CRAIG&category_group=SSSS&category=SBIK&level-country=GBR

but get error {"success":false,"error":"level params not supported in polling"}

when i do a location search it works using the metro field

http://reference.3taps.com/locations?auth_token=favvvvvvvvvv6f4a23a1cc86e0d&level=metro&country=GBR

```
"locations": [
{
"bounds_max_lat": 57.21864,
"bounds_max_long": -2.06182,
"bounds_min_lat": 57.10158,
"bounds_min_long": -2.22161,
"code": "GBR-ABD",
"full_name": "Aberdeen, United Kingdom",
"short_name": "Aberdeen"
},
{
"bounds_max_lat": null,
"bounds_max_long": null,
"bounds_min_lat": null,
"bounds_min_long": null,
"code": "GBR-BAT",
"full_name": "Bath, United Kingdom",
"short_name": "Bath"
},
```

but when i add this to my polling search , i cannot get this to return any values for bikes for sale in the uk?

http://polling.3taps.com/poll?auth_token=fa9xxxxxxxxxcc86e0d&anchor=2109915749&source=CRAIG&category_group=SSSS&category=SBIK&&level=metro&country=GBR

also used &location.city=GBR-MAN to find bikes in manchester which returns error

i get {"success":false,"error":"level, country params not supported in polling"}.

Comment: I don't understand how this has anything to do with Ruby or Rails.  It looks like the "3taps" service does not support this query.

Comment: i tried to add 3taps but need 1500 points and i didn't add ruby & rails tags it was suggested, when submitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the response says, the polling API of 3taps doesn't support "location.#{level}" parameters yet.  You have to use the search API of 3taps - try looking into the timestamp parameter to achieve a similar effect that you get from the polling API.

Comment: yep thanks , and it turns out 3taps only supports USA & Canada anyway!